# How do I make the marquee go behind my logo?

Tags: html, css

^title practically

i wanted to put my marquee to go behind my logo on my header. how do i do this?

I have tried lots of stuff, asked my classmates but no one came up with an idea.

so here's my html code

```
<img class="logo" src="logo.jpeg">
    <marquee>hello world</marquee>

     <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li> 
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <div class="filler">.</div>
    </ul>`
```

here's my css (used a lot of classes)

```
.slideshow {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px; 
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .slideshow2 {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: burlywood;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: chocolate;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .sd3 {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: darkgoldenrod;
        }

        .filler {
            color: bisque;
            background-color: bisque;
            font-size: 34px;
            padding-right: 16px;
        }

        .title {
            background-color: burlywood;
            color:#382E1C;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: sans-serif;      
        }

        .img1 {
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .bg {
            background-color: #BAA378;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .par{
            background-color: #BAA378;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #453823;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .pricedesc {
            background-color: chocolate;
            color:#382E1C;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .logo {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            opacity: 0.75;
            width: 225px;
            height: 125px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto; 
        }

         .filler {
            color: bisque;
            background-color: bisque;
            font-size: 34px;
            padding-right: 16px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: cornsilk;
            width:100%;
        }

        .navbar{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            display: block;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: bisque;
            color: chocolate;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: burlywood;
        }

        .active {
            background-color:chocolate;
            color: beige;
        }

        h1 {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            background-color: coral;
            color:blanchedalmond;
            text-align: center
        }
```

Comment: Please add your `code` to your question

Comment: `I have tried lots of stuff` - Please post the HTML, Script, CSS, etc.. anything you have tried so we can have a look to see why it doesn't work. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Comment: Can you please put some example code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is deprecated and I would consider removing it if possible (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: @zik what do i use?

Comment: You'd need to use JavaScript to create something similar. There are a few things that you could do in CSS to accomplish something similar. This has been asked before here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative

Comment: @zik we aren't allowed to use js because we haven't been taught of it yet

Comment: @teendoinghisprojects ah ok, my bad. Just something that I thought you should note though seeing as that tag is deprecated. You can achieve what you are asking using just CSS (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the image, and give it some higher `z-index`

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">
<marquee>marquee text goes here</marquee>
```

I've made the image transparent, so you can see the text going under it.

Comment: I tried it but the logo glitched into the nav bar. [for context](http://imgur.com/gallery/dP7f8)

Comment: You will need to push the menu to the right, add a left margin or padding of 225px (the width of your logo)

Comment: so i do `float:left;` on my nav bar and do `margin-left:225px;` on the logo?

Comment: add the margin on the `navbar` - [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/jqtfgjsL/)

Comment: but i need the logo to go on top not on the side tho

Comment: @teendoinghisprojects Then use relative position on the image and absolute on the marquee. - [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqtfgjsL/1/)