# How to add a HTML element before a certain HTML element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an HTML marquee element before the body element. I want to achieve this with javascript. I have searched all over for a way to do this but no success. Please help me.

One way I thought of doing it was

```
document.insertBefore('<marquee>', '<body>')
```

This gives me the error of

```
VM888:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Please help. Thank You!

Comment: You're inserting a String that says `<marquee>`, not an actual HTML element. You'll also want to insert the element into the `body`: https://jsfiddle.net/9udmks3g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with what you're trying to do:

1. The `<marquee>` element is **[obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)**; don't use it. Ever.
2. You shouldn't even be **attempting** to insert before `<body>`.
   **[The only valid children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)** of `<html>` are `<head>` and `<body>`, specifically in that order.
3. Third, you need to insert a DOM [**node**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not an **[HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)** (a type of node):

```js
// Create the node to insert
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.innerHTML = 'new';

// Set up the other nodes
var parent = document.getElementById("childElement").parentNode;
var child = document.getElementById("childElement");

// Insert it
parent.insertBefore(newNode, child);
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
   <span id="childElement"> existing</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! Also, why is marquee 'Obsolete'?

Comment: No problems! I'd conjecture that it's because of the effect it might have on usability. There's also the fact that mobile browsers don't have the memory to spare to support it correctly. There's more information (including possible alternatives) in [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative), which may be of use :)