# How to change the style of a marquee tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the height of a marquee tag depending on a calculation using javascript. 
I have tried this:

```js
/*jslint devel: true */

function maths() {
    "use strict";
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1080) + 1);
    document.getElementByTagName("test").style.height = x;
}

window.setInterval(function () {
    "use strict";
    maths();
}, 1);
```

```css
marquee{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <marquee id="test" scrollamount="30" height="">test</marquee>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated

 

**EDIT:**
I have successfully been able to change the height of a marquee tag using JavaScript. I am following the same strategy as before but instead of changing height, i want to change the scrollAmount (the scroll speed). It does not change. 
Thanks

```js
/*jslint devel: true */
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1080) + 1);
var w = Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 1);
var section1= document.getElementById("test");
var section = document.getElementById("test");




function resize() {
    "use strict";
    let heightLet=x.toString() + "px";
    //var marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);
    section.style.height = heightLet; 
    marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);
}


function scroll() {
    "use strict";
    let speedLet=w.toString();
     //var marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);
    section.style.scrollAmount = speedLet; 
    marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);
}


function read(){
    console.log(x);
}

window.onload = function () {
    console.log("x="+ x);
    console.log("w=" + w);
    resize();
    scroll();
    read();
    
}
```

```css
marquee{
    font-size: 40px;
    border: solid;
    position:  absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

div{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/marqueestyle.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="resize()">
        <div>
            <section id="test">

            <marquee>test</marquee>
            </section>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your best bet is to not use the [non-standard (and largely inadvisable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) `<marquee>` element.

Comment: Check this post, explains how to get rid of marquee tag and implement your own. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31951412/5842628

Comment: Would you have any idea how to change the 0% and 100% translation using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have added dev and section. Section height can change with js. And you can use section in div like docking object.So Marque text works different height points. 
I will glad if I help your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="resize()">
        <div>
            <section id="test">

            <marquee scrollamount="30" >test</marquee></section></div>
        <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//CSS File (style.css)

```
marquee{
    font-size: 40px;
    border: solid;
    position:  absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

div{
    position: relative;
}
```

//JS file (script.js)

```
/*jslint devel: true */

function resize() {
    "use strict";
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1080) + 1);

    let heightLet=x.toString() + "px";


var section= document.getElementById("test");

     //var marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);
        section.style.height = heightLet; 
        marqueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(section);

}

window.onload= resize;
```