# Text move from its starting point left to right

Tags: html, css, marquee

Text move still from its points from left to right as it is possible by marquee tag or i use jquery for this

```
<marquee direction="left">this is text we provide it</marquee>
```

[image]

```html
<marquee direction="left">this is text</marquee>
```

Comment: please Show your html

Comment: How is the `marquee` element still a thing? *Bangs head*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is <marquee> deprecated and what is the best alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative)

Comment: How can it be a duplicate of a question why marquee is deprecated?

Comment: firstly still then move left to right not full text move

Comment: Although "why" is missing from this question, it still is deprecated. Answers from "what is the best alternative" should apply here.

Comment: So it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I think the OP requires that the text is initially **static** ("Still") and then transitions to the end...which you can't do with a `marquee`. This is why the linked dupe would have strategies to acheive the desired result.

Comment: Like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dqwpqE

Comment: thanks  Paulie_D that I want

Answer (score 1):

If you want left to right, the `direction` attribute should be set to `right`.
If not, just leave it as right to left is default.

**Please note:** the marquee tag was deprecated a long time ago and should not be used.

According to MDN:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

[Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

```html
<marquee direction="right">this is text</marquee>

<marquee>this is text</marquee>
```

Comment: I know this i want still text then it moves

Answer (score 0):

Try the following > **Moving from left to right**

```
<marquee direction="right">Text move from its starting point left to right</marquee>
```

Try the following > **Moving from right to left**

```
<marquee direction="left">Text move from its starting point left to right</marquee>
```

Comment: I know this i want still text then it moves

Comment: @Anubhavpun when should it start moving?

Comment: And you want it to stop once it is on the left side?