# Marquee is not working properly in edge browser, it is blinking

Tags: html, css

I am using EDGE version 44. I tried to use Marquee but it's notworking. In chrome its working fine. I tried same code in EDGE it's blinking. Below is my code.

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</marquee>
```

Comment: why dont you use animation, check the browser compatiablity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is <marquee> deprecated and what is the best alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3, `marquee` is a deprecated tag in HTML5 and shouldn't be used. Also, your question has already been answered, see [Why is  deprecated and what is the best alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative)

Using CSS animations is the native way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: I used animations but in chrome it's working fine, but in EDGE it not scrolling entire text from left to right

Comment: @ramumothukuri What is your Edge version? According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation), animation support on Edge versions below 79 is unknown and most likely it isn't supported.

Comment: @ramumothukuri you say you used animations.... not in the code you have provided. We can't debug code we can't see. Regardless of that, don't use deprecated tags.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jquery animation its working fine in all browser.Here is the Url : -
[Marque Link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee/)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You should demonstrate how this solves the issue.