# How do I change the size of a marquee text?

Tags: html, marquee

How do I change the size of a marquee text? 
Please help. The marquee code I'm using right now, is this:

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="30">Sidebar Test</marquee>
```

Comment: Please note the `marquee` tag has been [deprecated](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-marquee-tag.html) for quite some time (though will still work in some browsers). Using [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative) is the best alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add CSS

```css
marquee {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="30">Sidebar Test</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
marquee{
font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="30">Sidebar Test</marquee>
```

Comment: It's always better to write some kind of explanation.

Comment: Also it is identical to my answer 5 minutes earlier

Answer (score 0):

Classic Html, style="font-size:50pt;"

```html
   <marquee style="font-size:50pt;" behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="30">Sidebar Test</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting for a marquee is here:  https://way2tutorial.com/html/html_marquee_tag.php

Addressing your specific question about font size, try this:

Consider how marquees work on different browsers - for example, I've noticed that Chrome renders a marquee better than safari - Safari tends to be a bit jittery (horizontally) [I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.04]

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, 2 ways are these

1. add `marquee{properties}` in `style.css`
   e.g.-

```css
    marquee{
        font-size:3em;
        width:10em;
        height:2em;
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
    }
```

```html
<marquee attribute_name = "attribute_value"....more attributes>
    One or more lines or text message or image
 </marquee>
```

2. use inline CSS. e.g.-

```html
<marquee style="color:green;font-size:2em;" attribute_name = "attribute_value"....more attributes>
    One or more lines or text message or image
 </marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HTML` : `style="font-size: 20px;" // you can change the figure as you prefer for the size`

The full `<marquee>` would be like this:

```
<marquee height="20" width="100%" bgcolor="white" marquee="" behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3" style="font-size: 20px;">Hello World !</marquee>
```