# How to fix marquee warning in React JS without help of any package?

Tags: html, reactjs, marquee

**Using marquee HTML tag**
in React JS Project the line of code is below:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5">
    My Text scrolling Right to Left Here
</marquee>
```

But why did the terminal give this warning below:

> Warning: Do not use  elements as they can create visual accessibility issues and are deprecated  jsx-a11y/no-distracting-elements

Comment: Because it's an accessibility issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative OFC, you could adjust/disable the linter for that rule https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/no-distracting-elements.md, but why? It goes against best practices.

Comment: marquee elements has been long dead. use css transition to create your moving animation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: it's obselete...

Comment: Now, I am not going to use marquee HTML tag
**Deprecated:** This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant **web standards**, maybe in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. **Avoid using it**, and update existing code if possible;
** Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.**
Thank you