# Html slider text with php data

Tags: php, html

I try to get a news text slider and i try to do it with marquee html code,
but its seams i do some thing wrong, i have try a few times to get it work and faild.
This is the current code

```
$html= '<marquee behavior="slide" direction="left">'.echo $row['title'].'</marquee>';
```

Comment: Remove the `echo` statement in the string concatenation: `$html = '<marquee behavior="slide" direction="left">'.$row['title'].'</marquee>';`

Comment: wow - I thought the `marquee` tag went out with the ark

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius me too! [It is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) though, so it might disappear sooner rather than later.

Comment: "its seams i do some thing wrong" - you should at least explain what that means

Comment: You can't `echo` within another `echo`. Learn about basic [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: [This might be interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative) as an alternative

Comment: In fact @BenM was correct that solved my problem of my question , but i also tank you to let me know a beather alternative with jquery. Also on my main was a litle error beacuse it was not in side the loop so only do once , because i was use slide and not scroll

Answer (score -1):

HTML **marquee** tag, already deprecated. You may use instead it Text-Scrolling-Plugin jQuery plugin

For more information  [Enter here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee/)

Additionally, enter your $text in other side and check it. Perhaps exits any error..

```php
echo $text;
```

Comment: The deprecated marquee tag is not the root problem with the given code

Comment: Also, the given snippet does not contain any variable named `$text`.