# I need to convert JQUERY code to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

I'm a wordpress developer, I know nothing from JS yet. I have found a way to make a marquee loop but I need the code in vanilla JS

this is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="bar">

    <a href="www.google.com">DIGITAL MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">BRANDING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">GRAPHIC DESIGN </a>
    <a href="www.google.com">WEBSITE DESIGN + DEVELOPMENT ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SITE MAINTENANCE ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SEO MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SOCIAL MEDIA MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">PHOTOGRAPHY ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">DIGITAL MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">BRANDING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">GRAPHIC DESIGN ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">WEBSITE DESIGN + DEVELOPMENT ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SITE MAINTENANCE ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SEO MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">SOCIAL MEDIA MARKETING ·</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">PHOTOGRAPHY ·</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 15000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 10,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

I tried chatgpt but withouth JS knowledge I don't find it possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. If you _know nothing_ about javascript, this might be a good opportunity to learn. Please try to solve this problem by yourself. If you are having difficulties with a specific programming problem, we will be happy to help you on that. Next time, please refer to the [ask] section before asking.

Comment: the `marquee` function does A LOT of things. I think the best bet for you is to pretend like you never heard of jquery and implement it from scratch - that's effectively the job anyway. How would you build a marquee from scratch?

Comment: @TKoL i wouldn't.

Comment: `$('.marquee').marquee` is not part of [tag:jquery] - so it must be a *plugin* - ie a third party solution that sits on-top of jquery.  Depending on its age and where you sourced it, there *may* be a non-jquery version of the same marquee so worth starting there.   Alternatively, search on SO for `marquee` and you might get an alternative solution [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31951552/2181514).

Comment: Looks like XY problem - rather than ask "how to do a looping marquee" you've asked "how to convert this random marquee I've found"

Comment: Note: the linked existing question *mostly* has jQuery answers, but there *is* a vanilla-javascript (no jquery) [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10547966/2181514)  (same question, just pointing to the relevant answer)